# Implementing RDT 3.0 protocol with timeout

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to implement the following protocol:

[image]

Specifically the S1, S2, and S3 phase

**My Thoughts:** 
I am setting a timeout in the socket.setSoTimeout()
which returns a SocketTimeOutException on socket.recieve()
I am not sure if that's a correct way to implement it
as in the diagram, it seems the timer should start immediately after sending the packet. 
I implemented the following:

```
rSocket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
try {
    rSocket.receive(packet);
}catch(SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException){
    return null;
}
senderSocket.send(datagramPacket);
    Packet responsePacket = Helper.recievePacket(rSocket);
    while(responsePacket==null){
        senderSocket.send(datagramPacket);
         responsePacket = Helper.recievePacket(rSocket);
    }
    if(responsePacket.isCorrupt() || responsePacket.getSequence()!=packetToSend.getSequence())
    {
        
    }
```

This does handle the part where the timeout happens due to the response being delayed.
But the program must wait until that `if` the condition is not satisfied. And in case of timeout again send the packet and wait for a response.
I am not sure what programming constructs in Java I could use here.

Comment: Interesting exercise :-) I suggest to take a step back and approach this as a state machine, not as direct code. The advantage of a state machine is that it is easier to reason about and to convince oneself that the implementation corresponds to the specs. Try not to increase the complexity by bringing in a state machine framework: probably better to learn about the basics of state machines and write a  simple one yourself. Good luck!

Comment: @marco.m Thanks for the suggestion. Could you suggest some good resources to read about state machine in general?

Comment: Although the examples are in Javascript, I think that this article is a good starting point  : https://dev.to/davidkpiano/you-don-t-need-a-library-for-state-machines-k7h.